# How to mock a function in TS file using Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

My jest setup has a `setupFile.ts` that runs before all tests run using the below `jest.config.ts` field:

```
  setupFiles: [
    "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/setup/setupFile.ts"
  ],
```

In that `setupFile.ts` I am attempting to mock out a function that I don't want to be called during my tests.  The file that I am trying to mock is called `PushNotifications.ts` and its contents look as below:

```
...
...
export async function sendNotifications(messages: Array<NotificationToSend>): Promise<void> {
  console.log('THIS SHOULD NOT FIRE AT ALL')
}
...
...
```

My `setupFile.ts` has the following code to attempt to mock the original implementation code for all tests that might call it.

```
import * as PushNotifications from "@common/PushNotifications";

jest.spyOn(PushNotifications, 'sendNotifications').mockImplementation(([]) => Promise.resolve());
```

However, this does not seem to work at all and I still am getting it called as I can deduce from my `console.log`.  This function is never called directly in my tests but instead called as side-effects of other functions being called (I don't know if that makes a difference). e.g.

```
async functionIDoWantToTest() {
   await sendNotifications(...) // Should ideally use mocked implementation from above
}
```

Comment: Spy the function inside your test file.

Comment: So there is no way to set this up in a setup file? @hoangdv  This function gets called by almost every route function that I call so I'd have to add this in to almost every test file I have.  That's fine if that's the only solution.

Comment: No, I guest. If you are writing unit tests, just do it like a normal unit case - mock dependency units and test for the current unit.

Comment: Well I guess what I am doing is more of an integration test / E2E test.  I am using supertest to hit a server endpoints and test actual output based on seeded results.   That might be where the difficulty is coming in.